# Notepad++ autoclosing tags that don't need it. How to turn off?

Tags: notepad++, html, tags

I just started learning HTML and am using Notepad++. I love the feature of autoclosing the tags, saves me a lot of time. I was wondering if there's a way for it to not autoclose the tags that don't need it, i.e. `<input>` or similar tags. I'd like to keep the option for all the other tags though. Thanks for checking out my question!

To summarize, when I type `<input>` it automatically puts `</input>` which is not needed in HTML. I'd like to get rid of that but keep the function for tags like `<p>`, `<body>`, `<head>`, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Go

> Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion

In the section labeled `Auto-Insert`, uncheck `html/xml close tag` and any others that might apply.

Comment: This seems to just not give me the option of auto completion while I'm typing the tags. What I would like to do is turn off the addition of closing tags automatically being put when there is no closing tag needed.

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was from memory, go back in there, and in the bottom section _Auto-Insert_, uncheck html close tags.